# Codeigniter Session variable not set

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am trying to set session variable using $this->session->set_userdata($booking_data) but it will not set session variable. My Controller is:

```
<?php

class Car extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {       
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model(array('Tariff_model', 'Category_model', 'Brand_model', 'Car_model', 'Booking_model'));
        $this->load->helper('formatting_helper');
    }

    function index($car_id = 0)
    {
        //price calculation
        $delivery_charge = $data['locations'][$this->input->post('start_location')]['delivery_charge'];
        $collection_charge = $data['locations'][$this->input->post('return_location')]['collection_charge'];
        $tax_vat = config_item('vat')/100;

        $booking_price = ($car->price_3*$total_days) + $delivery_charge + $collection_charge;
        $booking_price_vat = $booking_price*$tax_vat;                   
        $booking_total_price = $booking_price+$booking_price_vat;

        $booking_data = array(
            'car_id' => $car_id,
            'car_slug' => $car->slug,
            'vehicle' => $car->title,
            'start_location' => $this->input->post('start_location'),
            'start_date' => $this->input->post('start_date'),
            'start_time_hour' => $this->input->post('start_time_hour'),
            'start_time_min' => $this->input->post('start_time_min'),
            'return_location' => $this->input->post('return_location'),
            'end_date' => $this->input->post('end_date'),
            'end_time_hour' => $this->input->post('end_time_hour'),
            'end_time_min' => $this->input->post('end_time_min'),
            'discount' => '',
            'start_location_name' => $data['locations'][$this->input->post('start_location')]['name'],
            'return_location_name' => $data['locations'][$this->input->post('return_location')]['name'],
            'start_date_time' => $this->input->post('start_date').' at '.$this->input->post('start_time_hour').$this->input->post('start_time_min'),
            'return_date_time' => $this->input->post('end_date').' at '.$this->input->post('end_time_hour').$this->input->post('end_time_min'),
            'total_days' => $total_days,
            'total_price' => format_currency($booking_total_price)
        );

        $this->Booking_model->set_booking_data($booking_data);

    }
}

?>
```

And Booking_model.php :

```
<?php
Class Booking_model extends CI_Model
{

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function reset_booking_data()
  {
    $this->session->unset_userdata('booking');
  }

  function set_booking_data($data)
  {
    $booking_data = array();
    $booking_data['booking'] = array();
    $booking_data['booking'] = $data;

    // put our booking in the cart
    $this->session->set_userdata($booking_data);
  }

  function save_booking_data($data)
  {
    if(isset($data['id']))
    {
      $this->db->where('id', $data['id']);
      $this->db->update('orders', $data);
      return $data['id'];
    }
    else
    {
      $this->db->insert('orders', $data);
      return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
  }

  function get_booking_data()
  {
    $booking = $this->session->userdata('booking');

    return $booking;
  }

  function is_booking_data()
  {    
    $booking = $this->session->userdata('booking');

    if(!$booking)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  function orders($data=array(), $return_count=false)
  {
    if(empty($data))
    {
      //if nothing is provided return the whole shabang
      $this->get_all_orders();
    }
    else
    {
      //grab the limit
      if(!empty($data['rows']))
      {
        $this->db->limit($data['rows']);
      }

      //grab the offset
      if(!empty($data['page']))
      {
        $this->db->offset($data['page']);
      }

      //do we order by something other than category_id?
      if(!empty($data['order_by']))
      {
        //if we have an order_by then we must have a direction otherwise KABOOM
        $this->db->order_by($data['order_by'], $data['sort_order']);
      }

      if($return_count)
      {
        return $this->db->count_all_results('orders');
      }
      else
      {
        return $this->db->get('orders')->result();
      }

    }
  }

  function get_all_orders()
  {
    //sort by alphabetically by default
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $result = $this->db->get('orders');

    return $result->result();
  }  
}

?>
```

My `var_dump` output of `$booking_data` is:

```
array(1) {
    ["booking"]=> array(18) {
        ["car_id"]=> string(1) "7"
        ["car_slug"]=> string(19) "audi-r8-v10-spyder1"
        ["vehicle"]=> string(16) "Aston Martin DB9"
        ["start_location"]=> string(20) "premiere-velocity-hq"
        ["start_date"]=> string(8) "23/09/15"
        ["start_time_hour"]=> string(2) "10"
        ["start_time_min"]=> string(2) "00"
        ["return_location"]=> string(18) "birmingham-airport"
        ["end_date"]=> string(8) "24/09/15"
        ["end_time_hour"]=> string(2) "10"
        ["end_time_min"]=> string(2) "00"
        ["discount"]=> string(0) ""
        ["start_location_name"]=> string(20) "Premiere Velocity HQ"
        ["return_location_name"]=> string(18) "Birmingham Airport"
        ["start_date_time"]=> string(16) "23/09/15 at 1000"
        ["return_date_time"]=> string(16) "24/09/15 at 1000"
        ["total_days"]=> int(1)
        ["total_price"]=> string(8) "£744.00"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have sessions enabled? Show us your `php.ini` file

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the session library to start your CI session. Use this in your controller.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Or you can add it to your autoload configuration in so the session will always load. Be sure to set your session key in the configuration also otherwise the CI session won't work. If memory serves me right.